# Layer from JSON File

Tags: json, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a way to create a feature layer (or other queryable layer) from a local JSON file? I have a feature layer that was exported to JSON (not geoJSON) and need to display it completely offline. Is this possible?

Using ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.21